# How should a parent advise a relatively young son who chooses to retire early and be a loafer after he has achieved financial independence?

Tags: adult-child, money

The son is in his early 40s. He has achieved financial independence after a decade of patient saving and investing despite a lacklustre career and even losing his job a couple of times. The father feels proud that the son is able to take care of himself financially despite bad luck in life. The son has never given the father cause to worry, at least when it comes to money.

Recently, the son announces that he want to retire and become a loafer. Rather than stay in a job or start some business in order to contribute to society, the son prefers to loaf around and invest/trade full-time to earn a living.

As a parent, how would you advise the son?

Comment: There are some details that might matter; is the son married? Does he have dependents? Why does the father object to the plan? (People do all kinds of things for money, but as long as it works, few people call it "loafing".)

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: The son is married and has his own family. He can afford to support his family and even his parents.

Comment: Has the son actually said he wants to "be a loafer" (which I assume means "sit on the couch all day watching TV"), or does he have other ideas for his free time: volunteer for a charity, learn a hobby or craft, be more present for his family, travel and see the world?

Comment: Would you be open to including "should I be advising him" as part of this question as well?

Comment: I'm having a trouble reconciling "lackluster career" and "will become a loafer" with "can afford to retire in their 40's and still support both family and parents". I can't think of any people in their 40's that could afford to do that even in cases where they had great careers. The only possible explanation I can think of that makes sense is that the son is really good investing/trading but doing that is hardly loafing. Usually it's a bloody hard job. Unless of course you call say founding Facebook lackluster.

Comment: Honestly, if the son is 40, I don't think it is the job of parents to give unsolicited advice. Especially not if the motivation for the advice is not 'I am concerned you cannot provide for your family' but rather 'you are doing something that is different from my world view'.

Comment: @Ida, you have a point. Upvoted. The father should re-examine his view that he should impose his holier-than-thou view that certain activities are more socially useful than others and so, if his son does some wall-street kind of job full-time, he is useless to society.

Comment: @DRF, What the son did is indeed exceptional. Low job a few times and yet gain financial independence at a young age through investing. I guess the father is too eager for the son to be somebody better respected in society rather than be a nobody whom he perceives to play a non-useful role in society that does not contribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the father in this situation, the first thing I would do is thoroughly examine my life to find why I think that remaining idle after retirement is a bad idea.  Having developed philosophically sound reasons for continuing to work hard even when it is not necessary, I would then expound these to my son and try to bring him around to my viewpoint.

It's all very well to have a strong work ethic, but it doesn't automatically appeal to everyone.  It is a belief system and as such it must be vigorously proselytized.  I can't just wave my hands around and say it's a good thing; I have to tell my son *why* it's a good thing.  And I can't do that unless I *know* why and can articulate the reasons.

On the other hand, if I *can't* develop philosophically sound reasons for continuing to work hard even when it is not necessary, then my son is living right, and I should just shut up.

One more thing must be noted here: investing and trading full-time to earn a living does not automatically equate to loafing around.  Done properly, it is damn hard work, and significantly increases the common wealth.

Comment: +1 For great answer. Especially for the last paragraph. I strongly doubt that if the son is able to provide for his family and his parents he is really retiring to "loafing".

Comment: +1. You're right. Loafing is the wrong word. The son is not doing nothing. He is still doing something to earn a living. The father should not impose his own view that Wall-Street kind of job is not socially productive on his son.

Comment: Apparently Woody Allen once said this to why he was still working in his late seventies: *You know in a mental institution they sometimes give a person some clay or some basket weaving? It’s the therapy of moviemaking that has been good in my life. If you don’t work, it’s unhealthy—for me, particularly unhealthy. I could sit here suffering from morbid introspection, ruing my mortality, being anxious. But it’s very therapeutic to get up and think, Can I get this actor; does my third act work? (…) So I get pleasure from doing this. It’s my version of basket weaving.*